# Removing lines following double occurrence of a keyword in some files

Tags: bash

I have 10,000 files(molecule1.pdbqt ... molecule10000.pdbqt). Only some of them contains second occurrence of a keyword **TORSDOF**. For a given file, I want to remove all lines following the second occurrence, if there, including the line containing the second occurrence of keyword **TORSDOF**, while preserving the file names. Can somebody please provide a sample snippet, if possible without loop(s). Thank you.

```
$ cat inputExample.txt
ashu
vishu
jyoti
TORSDOF
Jatin
Vishal
Shivani
TORSDOF
Sushil
Kiran
```

```
$ cat outputExample.txt
ashu
vishu
jyoti
TORSDOF
Jatin
Vishal
Shivani
```

Comment: I'm sure there are a ton of clever ways to do it, but I'd use `grep -n TORSDOF file` to get the line numbers. If there is > 1 then `sed` to delete all lines after the second one  (or just print all the lines up to it)

Answer (score 1):

This could be done as

```
cat input.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/TORSDOF|//2g' | tr '|' '\n' > output.txt
```

- `cat input.txt` to print the file content
- `tr '\n' '|'` to form a single line string
- `sed 's/TORSDOF|//2g'` to replace the second and onward occurrence of the keyword
- `tr '|' '\n'` to split the long line string into multi-line file
- `> output.txt` to output the file

Comment: I think we have to remove `-n` from the `cat` command

Comment: I think we should rather remove the unnecessary `cat` command entirely.

Comment: How could we remove `cat` from here? Using `sed` to do the `tr`'s job?

Comment: No, using the shell to do `cat`’s “job” (which it doesn’t have in this case; the name `cat` is derived from *con**cat**enation*, so printing out a single file is just an instance of the [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) antipattern).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk '/TORSDOF/&&c++>0 {next} 1' inputExample.txt 
ashu
vishu
jyoti
TORSDOF
Jatin
Vishal
Shivani
Sushil
Kiran
```

Based on exactly the [same question](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/162097-sed-pattern-delete-lines-containing-pattern-except-first-occurance.html) outside SO.